# How to uninstall docker-engine?

Tags: docker

I have installed the docker with

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

When I tried to uninstall the package, I am facing the following error

```
$ sudo apt-get remove docker-engine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  docker-engine
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 28.5 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 454135 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing docker-engine (1.8.2-0~vivid) ...
Failed to stop docker.service: Unit docker.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package docker-engine (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-engine
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How am I to uninstall the docker package?

I am using Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: If you instead try to uninstall docker completely, see [How to completely uninstall docker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker?).

Answer (score 32):

#### Try it

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/{packagename}.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq {packagename}
sudo apt-get remove {packagename}
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Comment: This leaves files behind.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem but in Ubuntu 14.04. The way that I resolve this problem was:

First remove bad links:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/{packagename}.* /tmp/
sudo apt-get remove {packagename}
```

So now you can install it again:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-engine
```

Thats all.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Docker tries to stop itself upon uninstall, and you've never actually run it successfully so it's not running. Have a look at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/docker-ce.prerm`. It will look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Automatically added by dh_installinit/12.1.1
if [ -x "/etc/init.d/docker" ]; then
        invoke-rc.d docker stop || exit 1
fi
# End automatically added section
```

You can easily spot the logic flaw here: it assumes that if the init script exists, the docker daemon must be running. However, if you've installed it on a platform where it doesn't actually *work* (e.g. WSL, etc.) that won't be the case.

Since stopping docker is the only thing the `prerm` script does, and docker for sure isn't running on your system, just delete the file, after which you'll be able to `apt remove docker-ce` like normal.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like a Docker specific issue, rather like general installation problem.

Did docker ever work on that machine (as in: did the installation even succeed?)

I would start looking into `Failed to stop docker.service: Unit docker.service not loaded` and see if that leads to any more insights on what's going wrong. Seems like it's unable to stop the service.

You might need to read up a bit about systemd, I recommend [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) page. `journalctl` might be helpful as well, see [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs).

And then:

- Does docker.service exist?
- Can it be loaded?
- What's its status?
- What does it say if you start it?
- Stop it?

ps: Not a big fan of fully automated installation scripts. I don't see what's wrong with `apt-get install docker-engine`...

Comment: Thanks. 
There was another instance of docker.io on the same machine installed through aptitude. While installing docker.engine, it warned me but I still went ahead and installed the docker.engine. Then uninstalled docker.io and then tried to uninstall docker.engine. That is when I got this error. 
I know this is not very clean way to install.
Then reason I install from the automated installation script is because docker doc said so.
I solved by using ugliest possible method. i.e. rm /lib/systemd/system/docker.*; rm /usr/bin/docker; aptitude purge docker.engine.
Now clean install seems fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **remove everything** that comes with the Docker Toolbox (**including Docker Engine**).

You can execute this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Uninstall Script

if [ "${USER}" != "root" ]; then
    echo "$0 must be run as root!"
    exit 2
fi

while true; do
  read -p "Remove all Docker Machine VMs? (Y/N): " yn
  case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) docker-machine rm -f $(docker-machine ls -q); break;;
    [Nn]* ) break;;
    * ) echo "Please answer yes or no."; exit 1;;
  esac
done

echo "Removing Applications..."
rm -rf /Applications/Docker

echo "Removing docker binaries..."
rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker
rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
rm -r /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver*
rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

echo "Removing boot2docker.iso"
rm -rf /usr/local/share/boot2docker

echo "All Done!"
```

If you still have the depreciated **Boot2docker** and you want to get rid of it as well.

You can uninstall it by executing the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Uninstall Script

if [ "$(which boot2docker)" == "" ]; then
    echo "boot2docker does not exist on your machine!"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "${USER}" != "root" ]; then
    echo "$0 must be run as root!"
    exit 2
fi

echo "Stopping boot2docker processes..."
boot2docker stop && boot2docker delete

echo "Removing boot2docker executable..."
rm -f /usr/local/bin/boot2docker

echo "Removing boot2docker ISO and socket files..."
rm -rf ~/.boot2docker
rm -rf /usr/local/share/boot2docker

echo "Removing boot2docker SSH keys..."
rm -f ~/.ssh/id_boot2docker*

echo "Removing boot2docker OSX files..."
rm -f /private/var/db/receipts/io.boot2docker.*
rm -f /private/var/db/receipts/io.boot2dockeriso.*

echo "Removing Docker executable..."
rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker

echo "All Done!"
```